# yesno check is not working in jsp

Tags: javascript

I have the below jsp where the yesnoCheck works properly for Slot Specific Search condition but its not working for product search

```
<td>Slot Search</td>
<td>
<input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="yesCheck"/>Yes  
<input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="noCheck"/>No
<div id="ifYes" style="display:none">
Slot Start Time: <input type='text' id='Start' name='StartTime'><br>
Slot End Time: <input type='text' id='End' name='EndTime'><br>
</div>
</td>
</tr>                     
<tr>
<td>Product Search</td>
<td>
<input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno1" id="yesCheck1"/>Yes  
<input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno1" id="noCheck1"/>No
<div id="ifYes" style="display:none">
Product Number: <input type='text' id='yes' name='yes'><br>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
```

Below is my javascript function

```
function yesnoCheck() {
    if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked) {
        document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'none';

}


function yesnoCheck1() {
    if (document.getElementById('yesCheck1').checked) {
        document.getElementById('ifYes1').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else document.getElementById('ifYes1').style.display = 'none';

}
```

what i am doing my work here and how can i enable multiple yesno check option based on user input ?

Comment: In your product search you should call `yesnoCheck1`, no `yesnoCheck`...

Comment: Changed to product search to call yesnoCheck1, but its not still working

Comment: Fixed https://jsfiddle.net/7448vshe/

Comment: Thank you so much Hackerman !!

Comment: You are welcome @chimbu

Answer (score 0):

I've tided up your code a little and added `value` attributes and an event listener to each of the radio buttons.

```js
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll( 'input[type="radio"]' );

for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++ ){
 checkboxes[i].addEventListener( 'change', function(e){
   console.log( "You changed the " + e.target.name + " option to " + e.target.value );
    
    // do something with the result like if( e.target.name === slot && e.target.value === "yes" ){ ... }
     
  });
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td>Slot Search</td>
  <td>
    <input type="radio" name="slot" id="slot_yes" value="yes" />Yes
    <input type="radio" name="slot" id="slot_no" value="no" />No
    <div id="ifYes" style="display:none">
      Slot Start Time:
      <input type='text' id='Start' name='StartTime'>
      <br> Slot End Time:
      <input type='text' id='End' name='EndTime'>
      <br>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Product Search</td>
  <td>
    <input type="radio" name="product" id="product_yes" value="yes" />Yes
    <input type="radio" name="product" id="product_no" value="no" />No
    <div id="ifYes" style="display:none">
      Product Number:
      <input type='text' id='yes' name='yes'>
      <br>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```